# Using Included files in C++ projects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io

I just learnt the basics of C++. I know how to add a text file the project, but how do you refer to it in the program? Ultimately, I want to be able to have a list of outcomes in the text file and then my program randomly select a line. 
This is instead of using an external txt file. Thanks for your patience with my less-than-great question writing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you have to options to do what you desire:

- Put the possible outcomes in an external text file, then read the values from the text file from your C++ program when needed. The drawback is that the text file should be provided with your compiled executable program.
- Manually convert the text file with the possible outcomes to for example a C++ source file with for example a string array, and compile it into your program. This way no external text file is needed when running the program.

A third option would be to inclue the strings in the text file as a resource in the resulting executable, but it requires deeper understanding and the knowledge of Windows API to retrieve that values, so I do not recommend it to you ans you are just started C++ programming now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so if I were to place a text file in, say, appdata is there a way I can place that txt file from my within my program or will it have to be separate at the start, then relocated when the program is run. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the list of outcomes is (relatively) small, consider loading the file into vector of strings during startup and then get a line by index. Just write a function like this

```
int readStrings(const std::string sFileName, std::vector<std::string> &vOut);
```